# The published resource is not available currently. Contact your system administrator for further assistance

Tags: rdp, citrix

What does this error mean?  Yesterday, I re-installed the new Citrix Receiver on Windows 10.  I was successful launching a Remote Desktop session once in about a dozen tries since yesterday.  I've rebooted twice.  Two of those attempts, I was able to get the login prompt for RDP and when I logged into the RDP session, I got a black screen.  I've tried by launching the Citrix Farm on the website, using Internet Explorer and Google Chrome.  What else can I do to troubleshoot?

https://receiver.citrix.com

[Citrix Resource Icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oM9Gi.png)

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mg9NY.png)

Comment: Have you tried contacting your system administrator or are you the system administrator?